# Importing TensorFlow spawns threads

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, threadpool

I am running TensorFlow 0.10.0rc0 on an Ubuntu 14.04 server with 48 cores and python 2.7. I noticed that I have an unusual high thread count. I thought found the [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706950/how-many-processes-does-tensorflow-open) that TensorFlow will spawn multiple threads for two threadpools and that they can be [controlled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617638/tensorflow-mac-os-x-cant-determine-number-of-cpu-cores/33618045#33618045) by:

```
sess = tf.Session(
               config=tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=NUM_CORES,
                   intra_op_parallelism_threads=NUM_CORES))
```

However, that does not work and after some investigation, I found out that just calling `import tensorflow as tf` increases the thread count already by around 50-60.

Why is this happening? How can I prevent it and limit the actual number of threads? What are those extra threads doing if I limit the number of `inter_op_parallelism_threads` and `intra_op_parallelism_threads`?

Comment: `inter_op_parallelism_threads` controls how many simultaneous TensorFlow kernel calls can be launched, and `intra_op_parallelism_threads` controls size of Eigen threadpool. But TensorFlow treats threads as a cheap resource and spawns them for various things like callbacks. You can find more info by finding their names and tracking them down in code

Comment: Possible duplicate of the following question and answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62141945/keras-tf-cpu-creating-too-many-threads/64489297#64489297